# Mobile App height does not fit

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a small web browser in phonegap (just for learning) and I have an issuse. I'm using frameset as main tag to the page. Page is great, but it's just... It can be scrolled down. I want it to be fixed to the device.

I used meta tag but it changed just width.

Tried just height at CSS but still not worked:

```
height: 100%;
```

Maybe something else?
Any help?

Notes: frameset it's a simple frameset tag, no name untill now or other.

Comment: can you give us some code? or a fiddle?

Comment: Here is it. Now? Some help, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

</head>

<frameset rows="5%,30%,5%" noresize>
<frame src="files/urlbox.html"></frame>

<frame src="files/page.html"></frame>

<frame src="files/menu.html"></frame>


</frameset>


</html>
```